# Why var structs become let inside functions?

Tags: swift

Why a `var` `struct` becomes `let` when passed to a function?

```
struct S {
    var i: Int = 1
}

// this won't compile...
func changeS(s: S) {
    s.i *= 2  //  illegal: left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 's' is a 'let' constant
}

var s = S()  // struct defined as `var`
s.i *= 2     // and indeed this is legal
```

Answer (score 0):

Function input arguments in Swift are immutable by default. You need to mark the input argument as `inout` if you want to be able to mutate it inside the function.

```
struct S {
    var i: Int = 1
}

func changeS(s: inout S) {
    s.i *= 2
}

var s = S()
s.i *= 2
changeS(s: &s)
```

For more info, read the [functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) chapter of the Swift Language Guide.

Comment: Ok, so the real question would be 'why *any* var becomes let inside a function?' Nice if you can add ref to the docs. I'm yet in the tutorial =)

Comment: @Raf check my updated answer, included a link to the relevant doc page. Specifically, read the `In-Out Parameters` section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Because `struct` are not **reference-type**, but **value-type**.

This means that every time you pass a struct to another function, it gets **copied** into a new immutable struct (so it's a `let`).

If you change the value of the passed struct within a function, the original struct will not be affected, unless you tell the compiler that the param of the function is `inout`.

```swift
struct S {
    var i: Int = 1
}

// this will compile now with inout keyword
func changeS(s: inout S) {
    s.i *= 2  // now this is mutable and its change will be transferred back to the original struct.
}

var s = S()  // struct defined as `var`
s.i *= 2     // and indeed this is legal
changeS(s: &s) // notice the & before the var, it tells the compiler to pass the struct as inout param
```